# How to pass rowtype variable to an oracle procedure

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an oracle procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_row( p_rec IN table_name%rowtype )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_name
    VALUES p_rec;
END;
```

That I need to call from oracle APEX page and pass it several values. How can I do this, given the procedure takes in rowtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare
 l_rec  table_name%rowtype;
begin
 l_rec.id   := :P1_ITEM;
 l_rec.name := :P1_NAME;

 insert_row(l_rec);
end;
```